# Separación de cadena en serialización de objeto - Java (Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson

Tengo una inquietud sobre la serialización de un objeto usando ObjectMapper, ya que si uso el writter por defecto este me serializa el objeto, sin embargo, no me separa los items como se puede ver a continuación:

```
{"val1":1,"val2":3}
```

Deseado:

```
{"val1": 1, "val2": 3}
```

No es pertinente usar el DefaultPrettyPrinter porque lo necesito en una sola linea sin identación, pero si conservar los espacios entre las comas y los dos puntos.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature., true);

ObjectWriter objectWritter = objectMapper.writer();

String json = objectWritter.writeValueAsString(body);

System.out.println("output:" + json);
```

PD: Cree una expresión regular para solucionar el problema, pero creo que puede haber una solución directa (Así como python separa estos campos)

Muchas gracias por su colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que tu caso de uso es mas por un requerimiento estético y no tanto funcional por lo que mencionas.

El `DefaultPrettyPrinter` de Jackson es bastante configurable y puede que sea tu mejor opción. Puedes heredar de dicha clase y configurarla, o puedes usar los métodos que vienen dentro del `DefaultPrettyPrinter` para cambiar cosas como la identación, entre otros.

Habiendo dicho eso, intenté usar los métodos del `DefaultPrettyPrinter` pero no conseguí la sálida exactamente como la tienes en el ejemplo, así que opté por extender la clase.

A manera de ejemplo, y asumo hay mejores opciones :), el siguiente snippet imprime lo que estas buscando:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Sample {

    public static class A {
        private int val1;

        private int val2;

        public A(int val1, int val2) {
            this.val1 = val1;
            this.val2 = val2;
        }

        public int getVal1() {
            return val1;
        }

        public int getVal2() {
            return val2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        A a = new A(1, 3);

        DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new SamplePrettyPrinter();

        String result = mapper.writer(printer).writeValueAsString(a);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static class SamplePrettyPrinter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter {
        public SamplePrettyPrinter() {
            _objectFieldValueSeparatorWithSpaces = ": ";
            _objectIndenter = NopIndenter.instance;
            _spacesInObjectEntries = true;
        }

        public void writeObjectEntrySeparator(JsonGenerator g) throws IOException {
            super.writeObjectEntrySeparator(g);
            g.writeRaw(' ');
        }

        @Override
        public SamplePrettyPrinter createInstance() {
            return new SamplePrettyPrinter();
        }
    }
}
```

El ejemplo lo configuré basado en el ejemplo que proveiste y no tiene en cuenta otros casos (e.j. objetos anidados), entonces seguramente tocará probar con otras configuraciones dependiendo del caso concreto que tengas, es solo una guía para mostrar lo que puedes obtener con el pretty printer.

Espero sea de ayuda!